# \begin{align} not working as expected

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, align

In this small snippet of code, I'm doing quick derivation to arrive at an equation to be used later in the analysis:

```
$
|\vec{F}|=q|\vec{v}||\vec{B}|sin(\theta)\\
m\frac{v^2}{r}=qvB\\
\frac{2qV}{r}=qvB\\
\frac{2qV}{r}=qB\sqrt{\frac{2qV}{m}}\\
\frac{V}{r}=B\sqrt{\frac{q}{2m}}\sqrt{V}\\
$
\begin{equation}
\frac{V}{r}=\lambda\sqrt{V},\lambda\equiv B\sqrt{\frac{q}{2m}}
\end{equation}
```

I am admittedly new to LaTeX, but not to programming or mark-up languages. I included

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

to be able to use

```
\begin{gather*}
\end{gather*}
```

but this nor align is working on either side of the dollar signs. I receive the error:

```
Missing } inserted. <inserted text> } \end{gather*}
```

Any information on the reconciliation of this problem is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You don't need the `$` characters for `align*` or `gather*`.

Comment: Lorentz force and centripetal force of a charge in magnetic field? ;-)

Comment: Yup - specifically the Fine Beam Tube experiment for determining the charge-to-mass ratio of electrons!

Comment: Well, my students' favorite experiment. They like to deflect the beam with external magnets ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of the `align`, `gather` and `equation` environments must be typeset within of a  `$...$` pair, since those environments start the math mode for themselves. This is true for the starred variants of the mentioned environments as well.

Some side remarks:

- Use `\sin` instead of `sin` -- it's a math operator which should not be typeset in italics.
- `\dfrac{}{}` is (sometimes) a better replacement for nicer fractions.
- `\DeclairedPairedDelimiters{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}` is much better than `|some stuff|`

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}


\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\begin{document}
%$
%m\dfrac{v^2}{r}=qvB\\
%\dfrac{2qV}{r}=qvB\\
%\dfrac{2qV}{r}=qB\sqrt{\dfrac{2qV}{m}}\\
%\dfrac{V}{r}=B\sqrt{\dfrac{q}{2m}}\sqrt{V}\\
%$

\begin{align*}
\abs{\vec{F}} &=\abs{q}\abs{\vec{v}}\abs{\vec{B}}\abs{\sin(\theta)}\\
m\dfrac{v^2}{r}& =qvB\\
\dfrac{2qV}{r} &=qvB\\
\dfrac{2qV}{r} & =qB\sqrt{\dfrac{2qV}{m}}\\
\dfrac{V}{r} &=B\sqrt{\dfrac{q}{2m}}\sqrt{V}\\
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\dfrac{V}{r} &=\lambda\sqrt{V}  &\lambda\equiv B\sqrt{\dfrac{q}{2m}}
\end{align*}

\begin{gather*}
\dfrac{V}{r}=\lambda\sqrt{V},\lambda\equiv B\sqrt{\dfrac{q}{2m}}
\end{gather*}

\begin{equation}
\dfrac{V}{r}=\lambda\sqrt{V},\lambda\equiv B\sqrt{\dfrac{q}{2m}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd be tempted to insert `\quad` after the `\lambda\sqrt{V},` terms in the `gather*` and `equation` environments.

Comment: @Mico: I left that as an exercise to the OP -- he will realize that it doesn't look very nice. And if egreg's thunderbold should struck me down, I have to stand it ;-) Thanks anyway

Comment: shouldn't `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` be in the preamble?

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Yes, of course. I was in a hurry. Thanks for notifying me

Answer (score 0):

add this `\usepackage{amsmath}` right after `\documentclass` tag